# Unable to start activity with map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity

I am trying to use Google map in my application, but it crashes with strange error. I extends my class from `ActionBarActivity` maybe the reason is that? How I can fix this?

#### Layout FIle

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Map Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

         final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_map);

    }

};
```

#### Exception

```
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vavianlabs.spyur/com.vavianlabs.spyur.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:128)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at com.vavianlabs.spyur.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:14)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     ... 11 more
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.vavianlabs.spyur-2.apk]
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
10-08 23:44:27.305: E/AndroidRuntime(8797):     ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an old type of map fragment use the newer type of fragment called support map fragment to support any type of devices

**sample**

```
 <fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your referenced Google play service to your applciation and added necessary permission and meta data values in your ManifestFiles ? Because as the exception says it is not able to find the Maps class in your application.

Have a look at this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm